# How to condense duplicate records and take the predominant value for a data element?

Tags: ms-access, crosstab

I have the following columns in a table: [PO Concatenate], [Award], [Material Group]
There can be multiple entries with the same [PO Concatenate], but I want to be able to condense the entry into a single entry that consists of the [Award] SUM and the [Material Group] of the entry with the largest value.

For example: [PO Concatenate] "3140950_#" should result in one line with [Material Group] "E006" and [Award] = "$489.7" 
[image]

I've tried a crosstab query and while that reduces the repeats and sums the Award, it does not grab the correct Material Group. I just learned today that using First function prioritizes the first Alphanumeric item instead of the first value when I sort by Award in descending order. There is a standard field [FY/P] that I use.

UPDATE per @Applecore

```
TRANSFORM Sum([MG ETC].Award) AS SumOfAward
SELECT 
M.[PO Concatenate], 
Sum(M.Award) AS TotalAward,
(SELECT TOP 1 M1.[Material Group] FROM [MG ETC] AS M1 WHERE M1.[PO #]=M.[PO Concatenate] ORDER BY M1.Award DESC) AS TopGroup
FROM [MG ETC] AS M
GROUP BY M.[PO Concatenate]
PIVOT [MG ETC].[FY/P];
```

Is what I'm attempting even possible within Access?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery to return the Material Group that has the `TOP 1` Award value:

```
SELECT M.[PO Concatenate], 
Sum(M.Award) AS TotalAward, 
(SELECT TOP 1 M1.[Material Group] FROM [MG ETC] AS M1 WHERE M1.[PO Concatenate]=M.[PO Concatenate] ORDER BY M1.Award DESC) AS TopGroup
FROM [MG ETC] AS M
GROUP BY M.[PO Concatenate];
```

Regards,

Comment: I was able to get this query to somewhat get the result I wanted for a brief sec, but then I get the error "At most one record can be returned by this subquery". Any ideas?



SELECT
M.[PO Concatenate], 
Sum(M.SumofAward) AS TotalAward,
(SELECT TOP 1 M1.[Material Group] FROM [MGETCpreMG] AS M1 WHERE M1.[PO Concatenate]=M.[PO Concatenate] ORDER BY M1.SumofAward DESC) AS TopGroup
FROM [MGETCpreMG] AS M
GROUP BY M.[PO Concatenate];

Comment: This worked on data based on your original table, but it appears that you are now running this against a different query ("MGETCpreMG"), which I know nothing about.

Comment: Hi Applecore, let's say I go back to my original table/code, the one with the Transform. Would you be able to help me structure that code to include your subquery since I couldn't get it to work. The only change I would make would be changing your usage of [PO #] to [PO Concatenate] if possible?

Comment: Changing [PO #] to [PO Concatenate] in the original SQL using [MG ETC] works OK

Comment: I updated my code to what I believe is the direction you were helping me with. However, it is now giving me the error that M.[PO Concatenate] is not a valid field name or expresssion

Comment: Amended the original SQL to use [PO Concatenate]

Comment: Unfortunately still getting the error that M.[PO Concatenate] is not a valid field name or expression :\